# holes when filling faces with curved lines

Tags: modeling

I have this model here with a large curved surface, what I did was just select all the verticies like normally would and just press "F" to fill. However it ended up doing not that well of a job as now it's got some holes near the edge.
[image]
Any idea why this happens, and if my method is wrong in the first place, any way to easily fill in curved surfaces like this one?

Comment: If you press Ctrl+T you should see how it triangulates. Without even seeing the entire shape it's hard to advise something, rather than maybe not creating a single face, and dividing the shape to multiple faces that seem most logical (are convex)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Markus von Broady, triangulating the faces solved the issue. While at the end it isn't as smooth as I hoped it'd be, it's hardly noticable anyways lol.